# Class 'Application' not found, PHP

Tags: php

when I run my index.php, I get the following error :

Class 'Application' not found in: ../data/DSS/public/index.php

```
Index.php

        define ('ROOT' , dirname((__DIR__)) . DS);
        define('APP', ROOT . 'app'. DS);
        define('VIEW', ROOT . 'app'. DS . 'view'. DS);
        define('MODEL', ROOT . 'app'. DS . 'model'. DS);
        define('CORE', ROOT . 'app'. DS . 'core'. DS);
        define('DATA', ROOT . 'app'. DS . 'data'. DS);
        define('CONTROLLER', ROOT . 'app'. DS . 'controller'. DS);

        $modules = [ROOT, APP, VIEW, MODEL, CORE, DATA, CONTROLLER];
        set_include_path(get_include_path(). PATH_SEPARATOR . implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $modules));
        spl_autoload_register('spl_autoload', false);


        /* Starts the application*/
        $app = new Application();
```

It works fine in my localhost, where my WWWroot was /public, but on server is /data

Comment: What OS is your local env and your server? Are the folder and filenames the correct casing? That matters on some OS's and not on others.

Comment: Do you have some `.htaccess` on both server and local? They may also cause an error because of different mapping.

Comment: @Tarasovych yes I do,

Comment: @MagnusErikssonon local is windows and my server is unix. I used appropriate case where required.

Answer (score 0):

As for Application, it runs when you place

```php
include_once('Application.php');
```

right before

```php
$app = new Application();
```

But then, it then displays an error for homeController. I think that there should be a means of including all of the directories but as of now I am still looking for it.

[Edit: April 28, 2019]
As for the Application itself not working on an uploaded server, it is only a matter of which hosting you're using. My developed site was working fine on localhost. When I had tested it on two web hosting sites, it didn't work as well and only displayed a blank page or an error message. Upon testing it on a third web hosting site, it worked perfectly as it did on the localhost.